# How to convert a Numpy array of int to string in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy, int

How can I convert the Numpy array into a string?

```
data = rawTrainingData[0:25010,0:10]
labels = rawTrainingData[0:25010,10]

stringData = np.array(map(str,data))

print data[1]
print stringData[1]
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Just what kind of string do you want? Please show sample input and the desired resulting output. What is the point of the code you show--is it your attempt? If so, what is wrong with that attempt? And so on. Read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: right now I have the print out [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] for both. I want stringData[1] to print out ['0','1','2',....]

Comment: Your information is still not complete. What are the contents of `rawTrainingData`? And so on. Did you read the link I give you? Show us *complete code* that we can enter into our own Python and get results that show your problem.

Comment: try `data.astype('U')` or if you are on python2 `data.astype('S')`

Comment: Paul, Thank You! That is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 2):

try data.astype('U') or if you are on python2 data.astype('S') – Paul Panzer